# Using regular expressions to find a pattern

Tags: python, regex

If I have a file that consists of sentences like this:

```
1001 apple
1003 banana
1004 grapes
1005 
1007 orange
```

Now I want to detect and print all such sentences where there is a number but no corresponding text (eg 1005), how can I design the regular expression to find such sentences? I find them a  bit confusing to construct.

```
res=[]
with open("fruits.txt","r") as f:
     for fruit in f:
          res.append(fruit.strip().split())
```

Would it be something like this: `re.sub("10**"/.")`

Comment: If your input only ever consists of either `NUMBER WORD` or `NUMBER`, then you don't need a regular expression and can instead just split the line: if there are two elements, then you've got `NUMBER WORD`, if you've only got one, you've got what you're looking for.

Comment: You misunderstand what `*` does in a regular expression, it's not a wildcard character.

Answer (score 4):

Well you don't need a regular expressions for this:

```
with open("fruits.txt", "r") as f:
    res = [int(line.strip()) for line in f if len(line.split()) == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex that would detect a number, then a space, then an underscore word is `([0-9])+[ ]\w+`.

A good ressource for trying that stuff out is http://regexr.com/

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the extra braces are technically unnecessary. A simple space character will suffice, though the braces do help to make the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The re pattern for this would be `re.sub("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")`. This looks if there are only four numbers and nothing else, so it will find your 1005.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this: `search()` and `findall()`. The former will find the first instance of a match, and the latter will give a list of every match.

In any case, the regex you want to use is `"^\d{4}$"`. It's a simple regex which matches a 4-digit number that takes up the entirety of a string, or, in multiline mode, a line. So, to find 'only number' sections, you will use the following code:

```
# assume 'func' is set to either be re.search or re.findall, whichever you prefer
with open("fruits.txt", "r") as f:
    solo = func("^\d{4}$", f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
# 'solo' now has either the first 'non-labeled' number,
# or a list of all such numbers in the file, depending on
# the function you used. search() will return None if there
# are no such numbers, and findall() will return an empty list.
# if you prefer brevity, re.MULTILINE is equivalent to re.M
```

Additional explanation of the regex:
`^` matches at the beginning of the line.
`\d` is a special sequence which matches any numeric digit.
`{4}` matches the prior element (`\d`) exactly four times.
`$` matches at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
(?:^|\s+)(\d{4}\b)(?!\s.*\w+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lC9qR9/1)